# No System.Web In VS2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reference, system.web

In a WPF project, I'm trying to add System.Web as a reference but in Project -> Add Reference -> .NET there's no System.Web.

[alt text http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/3406/addreference.png](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/3406/addreference.png)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you targeting the client profile rather than the full version of the framework?

I think the default target type in VS2010 for client applications (WPF, WinForms etc) is the client profile, which doesn't include `System.Web`.

Comment: Thanks (can accept answer only in 10 minutes :S). What is client profile?

Comment: From MSDN: "The .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is a subset of the .NET Framework 4 that is optimized for client applications." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx

Comment: Note that you can pick the target framework in the 'new project' dialog, or after creating a project, right click the project and select 'properties' and change the application's properties to choose the target framework you want.